# How to do I get the message of the command user after my bot asks a question?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to create a Discord music bot. When someone does !play (song name), it will Google search song name and take all the links with "youtube.com/watch" and download it. Right now I figured out how to do this locally in terminal. The problem is I don't know how to ask the author of the command what song choice they want if multiple links show up with "youtube.com/watch"
Here is my code:

```
ytlinks = searchForLink(link, 10)
# ask which link
if len(ytlinks) > 1:
    await ctx.send(str(ytlinks))
    await ctx.send("Which link do you want to use?")
    # want code here to take next message after the "Which link do you want to use?" and set to var "linkchoice"
    linkchoice = ''
    if (not int(linkchoice) <= 10) or (not int(linkchoice) >= 1):
        await ctx.send("Not an integer or not valid option")
    linkchoice = int(linkchoice) - 1
    ytlinks = ytlinks[int(linkchoice)]
```

Comment: do you know about `wait_for`? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for

Comment: @moinierer3000 I am fairly new to coding, so I am not sure how to implement "wait_for" in a command. In the documentation it is used in an on_message event, how do I use this in my command code?

Comment: Sure, I have written a comment below with an example. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment, heres a basic example with your code on how you can implement `wait_for`.

```py
#just hardcoding some list for demonstration purposes
ytlinks = ["https://youtube.com/123", "https://youtube.com/456", "https://youtube.com/789"]

if len(ytlinks) > 1:
    await ctx.send(str(ytlinks))
    await ctx.send("Which link do you want to use?")

    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author

    try:
        message = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=60.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        ctx.send("You took too long to respond!")
        return
    else:
        linkchoice = message.content
        if (not int(linkchoice) <= 10) or (not int(linkchoice) >= 1):
            await ctx.send("Not an integer or not valid option")
            return
        await ctx.send(f"You chose link #{linkchoice}:\n{ytlinks[int(linkchoice)-1]}")
```